# Why isn't my text saving when i leave the activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a notes app and basically i want it to save the text input and restore it when i return to the activity. But why isn't my code doing that? I tried onRestoreInstancestate and onRestore but it's not working. Any one know how i can save the text input after i exit the app?

notes.java:

```
public class notes extends Activity{




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);




        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }   
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: if you `finish()` you tell Android that your app shall not be restored. There is also no code that really saves your text. See [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or so

Comment: so i take it out and put and place super.onRestore() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here you have the working, tested code

**notes.java** (`src\izzy\n\notes.java`)

```
package izzy.n;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

// actually you should name the class "Notes" since it's convention
// but it would proably cause errors since you have to rename the file then.
public class notes extends Activity {
    public static final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Write some text here";
    public static final String PREFS_KEY_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    private EditText mEditText;

    /**
     * Loads the text from SharedPreferences
     */
    private String loadText() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(notes.PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return settings.getString(notes.PREFS_KEY_TEXT, notes.DEFAULT_TEXT);
    }

    /**
     * Saves text to SharedPreferences
     */
    private void saveText(String text) {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(notes.PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(notes.PREFS_KEY_TEXT, text);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes);

        // when you click on the button the app will exit
        // you kind of don't need such a button :)
        Button wg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        wg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        String savedText = loadText();
        mEditText.setText(savedText);
        // put the cursor to the end.
        mEditText.setSelection(savedText.length());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        saveText(mEditText.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

**notes.xml** (`res\layout\notes.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter Text here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**What you get**

[image: how it looks]

PS: You should maybe start reading some basic Java tutorials since you seem to have problems with basics :)

Comment: It's not a complete code example and written directly in this editor - it might even contain syntax errors etc. You need to adjust it so it works for you. E.g. you have to add the code you do in `onCreate` that I left out and you have to make sure that there is an EditText in `notes.xml` with `android:id="@+id/edit_text1"`. And if you are more specific than "lot of errors" I could help you more.

Comment: I will do what i can right now to adjust it to my code, and i will get back to you right away ;)

Comment: in my xml edittext is actually editText1 except when i change it, it does not recognize it for some reason]

Comment: If the id in the xml is `"@+id/editText1"` then you could change the code to `... findViewById(R.id.editText1);`. They just need to match. `mEditText` is a variable that stores a reference to the `EditText` Object so at the end in `onStop` you don't need to find the reference again. You could replace `mEditText.getText()` with `((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1)).getText()` if you wanted but that does not look so nice

Comment: Unfortunately no :) I have put the correct source code for you in my answer.